# what's meaning of "-backend=lmdb"

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I am new one to ubuntu and caffe. Now I am studying using caffe for image classification by the following link instruction (http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/).

Could you tell guys tell me the meaning the ""-backend=lmdb" in the following command:

```
/home/ubuntu/caffe/build/tools/compute_image_mean -backend=lmdb /home/ubuntu/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input/train_lmdb /home/ubuntu/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/input/mean.binaryproto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command runs a tool that computes mean pixel values to be used for image preprocessing. Mean values are computed using the entire training set. Caffe often uses datasets of format `lmdb` or `leveldb` the command switch `--backend` simply tells caffe to look for `lmdb` format.